# How to fetch Auth0 user information with code got from Login API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, auth0

I am using Ruby on rails for developing my web application and using gem auth0, and I am integrating Auth0 with Onelogin and using custom sign in form. When I tries to sign in with Onelogin I am being redirected to Onelogin, there I enter my onelogin credentials and I am being redirected back to my application as expected, and I get these parameters in response but no user details. My question is which is the API I should use to fetch user detail which has recently logged in through this code?

```
{"code"=>"aE0HE0S7ES6dEMRu", "controller"=>"auth0", "action"=>"callback"}
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to configure OneLogin as Identity Provider within Auth0? If so, have you gone through [Configuring OneLogin as an Identity Provider](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/identity-providers/onelogin) documentation?